# Trying to change the text using onclick in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm newbie to React JS. I'm trying to workout setState sample program to change the text while clicking the button using below code.

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react'

 class StateExample extends Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        message : 'state example'
    }
}
 changeMessage() {
    alert("I was clicked");
    console.log(this);
    this.setState = ({
        message : 'changed to hai'
    })
} 
/* handleEvent = event => {
    alert("I was clicked");
  }; */
render(){
    return ( 
        <div>
        <h2> {this.state.message} </h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.changeMessage()}>Click on me</button>
        </div>

    )
   }
 }

 export default StateExample
```

No error or warning occurs.alert is working while clicking,but text is not changing.

Console is returning below things which doesn't having **setState**. Is this the reason?

```
  [object Object]: {_reactInternalFiber: Object, _reactInternalInstance: Object, context: Object, isMounted: undefined, props: Object...}

 _reactInternalFiber: Object

 _reactInternalInstance: Object

 context: Object
 isMounted: undefined

 props: Object

 refs: Object
 replaceState: undefined

 state: Object

 updater: Object

 __proto__: Object
```

Notify my mistake.Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is a function:

```
this.setState = ({
    message : 'changed to hai'
})
```

Change to:

```
this.setState({
    message : 'changed to hai'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is a function, do not call it with the assignment operator.

Change:

```
this.setState = ({
    message : 'changed to hai'
})
```

To:

```
this.setState({
    message : 'changed to hai'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

## 1. Call the `this.setState` to update the state.

It's not a property or an object of `this`. It's a method you call to update state with.
And you should never mutate the state directly, as React wouldn't know that the state has changed. (⚠ do not do e.g.) `this.state = {message: 'change to hai'}`)

You need to update the state like you are calling a method.

```
this.setState({ message: 'changed to hai' })
```

## 2. `this` isn't available within `changeMessage` method.

There are two ways to fix the issue.

1. Bind the `changeMessage` within the constructor.

```
class StateExample extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        message : 'state example'
    }

    // ... Bind current Component's `this` to `changeMessage`
    this.changeMessage = this.changeMessage.bind(this)
  }
}
```

2. Second way is using new ES6 "[arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)" syntax.

Without adding the `bind` in the constructor, change the declaration of `changeMessage` to

```
changeMessage = () => {
  ...
}
```

Arrow methods do not create `this` of its own, thus will be using `this` from the calling context.

Comment: They are not doing this.state = they are doing this.setState = (which is equally wrong). Otherwise great answer.

Comment: @CalIrvine I realized it late and updated the answer  Thanks for catching the error  The answer should reflect that one shouldn't assign a state to `setState` like an object assignment but call it as a method.